# Meteor/MongoDB Duplicate Array Object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am curious what the best approach might be to create a button in meteor to duplicate an array object. As an example if I had:

```js
"TasksWithData": [
  {
    "inspectionDetails": [
      {
        "name": "somename",
        "inspector": "Ss6TjGGzqWJRZYStx",
        "inspectorName": "name of inspector",
        "projectType": "inspection",
        "startDate": "2017-01-12T05:00:00.000Z",
        "desc": "a description",
        "activeTask": true
      }
    ],
    "TaskItem": [
      {
        "DataFacilitySection": "dsfgsdfgds",
        "DataItemDescription": "item 2",
        "DataItemSection": "dfgdfgdf",
        "DataItemCode": "dfgdfgdf",
        "DataItemPass": null
      }
    ],
  }
],
```

If I wanted to duplicate the entire TasksWithData Array (which is a sub-document and does not have an _id) with a client button...how would I do this?

Here is the event I am calling:

```js
  'click .duplicate': function(){
    Meteor.call('duplicateItem', this._id);
  }
```

and here is the template structure:

Inspections/AddInspectionsHome:

```html
<template name="AddInspectionHome">
  <div class="container single-list conatiner-padding">
    <h1>Task Navigator</h1>
    <hr>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading no-padding">
          <span>Select a Client</span>
        </div>
        {{#each findClients}}
          {{> SingleClientInspection}}
        {{/each}}
      </div>
  </div>
  <!--TODO: Need to add the ability to duplicate these inspections-->
</template>
```

Inspections/SingleClientAddInspection (the ReactiveVar Mode that triggers the users ability to see active inspections):

```html
{{#if activeMode}}
    <div class="panel panel-default col-lg-12">
      <a href="#" class="active btn btn-primary">Close</a>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">View Active Tasks</div>
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Facility</th>
                <th>Inspector</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Due Date</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {{#each TasksWithData}}
                {{#each inspectionDetails}}
                  {{#if activeTask}}
                    <tr>
                      <td>{{TaskFacility}}</td>
                      <td>{{inspectorName}}</td>
                      <td>{{projectType}}</td>
                      <td>{{startDate}}</td>
                      <td><a href="#" class="duplicate btn btn-success">Copy</a></td>
                    </tr>
                  {{/if}}
                {{/each}}
              {{/each}}
            </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  {{/if}}
```

Comment: Duplicate it to where? To another mongo document? To a temporary variable? To another key within the same mongo document?

Comment: Actually, I really would like to just add it as a new identical object to the same array. The client wants the ability to duplicate a previously set up inspection so they don't have to re-add them from scratch. All of these inspections really need to live in the same array like above.

Comment: Also I edited my above code. My bad. I forgot to close of the parent object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest first extracting the original array then concatenating it back onto itself.

```
const doc = MyCollection.findOne(_id); // however you get your original doc
let TasksWithData = doc.TasksWithData;
TasksWithData.concat(TasksWithData);
MyCollection.update(_id,{$set: {TasksWithData: TasksWithData}});
```

Comment: Great thanks I will give this a shot as a method tied to a click event. Will report back tomorrow! Thanks for taking the time man!

Comment: Well this feels like its getting close, but I have a few issues I need to get through. I will update my original post and see what you think! Again thanks for the help on this one!

Comment: Since your event handler is running on the array itself you can get the `_id` of the parent object with `Template.parentData(1)._id`

Comment: Thank sweet 7lb 6oz BABY JESUS! This is exactly what I have been lacking for more than just this scenario! I really actually like Blaze, and hope  MDG finds a way to keep it around, but DOM traversal (or in this case template) has been a major sticking point for me. Is there a good place in the docs that I can read more on these? Cheers brother and thanks for the effort!

Comment: Hey @Michel I actually have one small issue using this method. Since you were so great at responding (and I have a tight deadline haha) might you be able to take a look at this related issue? [autofom update not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41646401/autoform-update-not-working)