# AutoForm Update Not Working

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-autoform

I am having some difficulty getting an autoform to save. This is a new issue for me; so I am a little unsure on how to fix it.

I have the following form:

```html
<template name="TaskItems">
  {{#if inspectionMode}}
    <a href="#" class="inspection btn btn-danger">Close Task <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></a>
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Facility Section</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Section</th>
          <th>Code</th>
          <th>Pass/Fail</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {{#each TaskItem}}
            <tr>
              <td>{{DataFacilitySection}}</td>
              <td>{{DataItemDescription}}</td>
              <td>{{DataItemSection}}</td>
              <td>{{DataItemCode}}</td>
              <td>
                {{#autoForm id=itemUpdateForm collection="ClientData" type="update" autosave=true template="custom" doc=this}}
                  {{> afFormGroup name="DataItemPass" label=false}}
                {{/autoForm}}
              </td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    {{else}}
    <a href="#" class="inspection btn btn-success">Begin Task <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

The id logic is here:

```js
  itemUpdateForm: function() {
    return Template.parentData(2)._id;
  },
```

I did add `SimpleSchema.debug = true;` and it gives the following error:

***SimpleSchema.clean: filtered out value that would have affected key "DataItemPass", which is not allowed by the schema***

The field is pulling in the correct data (the field is filled out) but when I click off the field it does not save. I tried adding a submit button to see if that may change things, but it had no effect.

I can add the schema to the post if that is helpful. Any suggestions would be most appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure autoform can update the grandparent document.

Comment: Hmmmmm autoform is all that I am super comfortable with...what other approach might you suggest?

Comment: Forms are not hard, just build a form and send the data to a method whenever any of the fields change using an event handler.

Comment: You might get better help if you describe your problem as trying to define an autoform on a sub-key of a collection - i.e. you don't want the root keys in the form but you want a form for each array element.